# How to disable depth buffer in Directx11

Tags: directx, directx11, depth-buffer

For now i know what i must use OMSetDepthStencilState. In the beginning i must create two states and change them every time i need another. For now i have this and it doesn't work, i.e. *objects rendered in order i draw them*:

```
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = TRUE;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = FALSE;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

ID3D11DepthStencilState *m_DepthStencilState;
HR(m_Device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_DepthStencilState));
m_ImmediateContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_DepthStencilState, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
```

to

```
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
```

Comment: in theory, together with **DepthEnable = FALSE** it should turn off depth buffer, but it doesn't work without setting its state and if set it either. I need first to make it work.

Comment: You may want to look at [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) ``CommonStates`` helper. It creates some depth-buffer state objects that handle standard depth, read-only depth, and no-depth.